# Cron Jobs in NestJS schema-based multitenancy application using TypeORM and Bull

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, jobs, bull

In my application there are several "partners", where each one is a tenant. Is there any way for each partner to perform the same jobs at the same scheduled time using Bull repeat option? Example: all partners every day at 8 AM must perform the "wake up" job and at 9 AM the "breakfast" job. An even better approach would be: as soon as the "wake up" job, scheduled for 8 AM, completes without errors, start the "breakfast" job.

These jobs would modify the partner database so I need to know how to separate the contexts and each job be executed by each partner in the right way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.